# How do I listen to TPL TaskStarted/TaskCompleted ETW events

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, etw

I am interested in listening to ETW (event tracing for Windows) TPL events, in particular I'd like to know when a `Task` starts and when it stops.

Here's a sample program I've used for testing:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApplication10
   {
      class Listener : EventListener
      {
         private static readonly Guid tplGuid = new Guid("2e5dba47-a3d2-4d16-8ee0-6671ffdcd7b5");

         protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Got guid: " + eventSource.Guid);
            EnableEvents(eventSource, EventLevel.LogAlways);
         }

         protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Event: " + eventData.EventId);
         }
      }

      class Program
      {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            using (var listener = new Listener())
            {
               Action doIt = null;
               doIt = () =>
               {
                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
                  Console.Write('.');
                  Task.Run(doIt);
               };
               Task.Run(doIt);

               Parallel.Invoke(() => Console.WriteLine("invoke"));

               Console.Read();
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Sample output is as follows on my machine:

```
Got guid: 8e9f5090-2d75-4d03-8a81-e5afbf85daf1
Got guid: 2e5dba47-a3d2-4d16-8ee0-6671ffdcd7b5
Event: 3
invoke
Event: 4
.......
```

So the Invoke method causes an event to fire, yet the Tasks fire none. Looking at the Task source (e.g. [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2812)) the code appears no different from how the `Parallel.Invoke` event fires.

What is wrong with the above, or, how do I listen to TaskStarted and TaskCompleted events (or *any* Task related event for that matter)?

Comment: When you finish the task, you should invoke a finished task function on the main thread. You can pass this finish function as an `Action` through the parameters.

Comment: I have very similar code working (receiving TPL events such as TraceOperationBegin) and I can't see what the difference is in my code offhand. I'll have to try to figure it out. Anyway, right now I doubt that you need an out-of-box library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question challanged me to look into ETW (which I've been wanting to look into for a while). I was able to capture *"task start"* and *"task end"* using [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent NuGet library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) with the simple following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var session = new TraceEventSession("TplCaptureSession"))
        {
            session.EnableProvider(new Guid("2e5dba47-a3d2-4d16-8ee0-6671ffdcd7b5"),
                                   TraceEventLevel.Always);

            session.Source.Dynamic.AddCallbackForProviderEvent("System.Threading.Tasks
                                                               .TplEventSource",
                "TaskStarted", @event =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inside Task Started");
                });

            session.Source.Dynamic.AddCallbackForProviderEvent("System.Threading.Tasks
                                                   .TplEventSource", 
                "TaskCompleted", @event =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inside Task Stopped");
                });

            session.Source.Process();
        }
    });

    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(20000);
    });

    task.Wait();
}
```

Basically what happens is:

1. We start new a live event capturing session using `TraceEventSession` where we pass it `TraceEventLevel.Always` to print out all messages (we could narrow this down to `TranceEventLevel.Information`, but for the example I chose all).
2. We enable the TplEventSource provider by passing its `Guid` to `session.EnableProvider`.
3. We register a callback to be invoked once `TplEventSource` (which is the event source for TPL, obviously) fires either `TaskStarted` or `TaskCompleted` events (taken from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs))
4. We print out once we're inside the event.

Note my use of `Task.Run` was simply because `session.Source.Process()` is a blocking call, and I wanted it to run in the background.

Comment: Although I'm still curious why my code does not work, this did the trick for  me, thanks.

Comment: @Marcus Welcome. I think it's even easier now once they built the `TraceEvent` library.

Comment: Instead of `TaskExecute/Start` and `TaskExecute/Stop`, I had to use `TaskStarted` and `TaskCompleted`

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/9c2b5d74d144852718e5b788d22b7fc0) of code I wrote that listens to TPL ETW events using only the BCL.

The [part that tripped me up](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/9c2b5d74d144852718e5b788d22b7fc0#file-asyncvoidverificationscope-cs-L49) was the fact that you need to run this code:

```
// Cause the type initializer for System.Threading.Tasks.TplEtwProvider to run.
// Otherwise async method builders starting events will be missed.
Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.TplEtwProvider, mscorlib", true).GetField("Log").GetValue(null);
```

Otherwise, everything just seems to work the way you'd expect. No need for third-party libraries!

Answer (score 1):

Base on [Yuvals answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542409/4227) that didn't work for me because the event names seem to be different, I have come up with a solution that is typesafe and does not use magic guids or strings:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers.Tpl;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;

...

Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (var session = new TraceEventSession("TplCaptureSession"))
    {
        session.EnableProvider(TplEtwProviderTraceEventParser.ProviderGuid, TraceEventLevel.Always);

        var parser = new TplEtwProviderTraceEventParser(session.Source);
parser.AddCallbackForEvent<TaskStartedArgs>(
            null,
            @event =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Task {@event.TaskID} started by {@event.OriginatingTaskID}");
            });

        parser.AddCallbackForEvent<TaskCompletedArgs>(
            null,
            @event =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Task {@event.TaskID} completed");
            });

        session.Source.Process();
    }
});
```

And for completeness, here is a list of event names I have seen being generated by the `System.Threading.Tasks.TplEventSource` source:

- AwaitTaskContinuationScheduled/Send
- DebugFacilityMessage
- DebugFacilityMessage1
- DebugMessage
- EventSourceMessage
- ForkJoin/Start
- ForkJoin/Stop
- IncompleteAsyncMethod
- Invoke/Start
- Invoke/Stop
- Loop/Start
- Loop/Stop
- ManifestData
- NewID
- RunningContinuation
- RunningContinuationList
- SetActivityId
- TaskCompleted
- TaskScheduled/Send
- TaskStarted
- TaskWait/Send
- TaskWaitContinuationComplete
- TaskWaitContinuationStarted
- TaskWaitEnd
- TraceOperationBegin
- TraceOperationEnd
- TraceOperationRelation
- TraceSynchronousWorkBegin
- TraceSynchronousWorkEnd